# Old Google Chrome automation using Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I have to automate for Google Chrome old versions such as 5,6,7...till the latest version. I see that chromedriver is available from version 13 onwards. Where can I find for the older version of these?

If I can't automate using webdriver, does selenium 1.0 supports all the older versions of google chrome? Is there a way to merge selenium 1.0 and webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) (all the way down):

> the ChromeDriver is only compatible with Chrome version 12.0.712.0 or newer

That's good news, one more version to work with, it's compatible with Chrome 12+!

Let's read on:

> If you need to test an older version of Chrome, use Selenium RC and a
>   Selenium-backed WebDriver instance:
>
> ```
> URL seleniumServerUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4444");
> URL serverUnderTest = new URL("http://www.google.com");
> CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(seleniumServerUrl, serverUnderTest, DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
> WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor);
> ```

This is worse, but still good, you can write WebDriver-like code and be backed by Selenium RC. That's written in pure JavaScript and therefore should work in any well configured and JavaScript-friendly browser. Chrome has always been JS-friendly, so chances are you'll get it to work everywhere!